# Limit function execution time

Tags: c++, macos, xcode6

Is there any way to make a function execute it's code for a specific time, then pause it's execution and move on to another function. I want to be able to make a program that can multitask. I have already tried using `<thread>`, but whenever I try to run the program it runs one of the threads partially and then the debugger throws a "signal SIGABRT" and stops. Is there any other way of doing this?

**Edit:**

Here is the code I tried using the threads with. I made this as a test in order to try to get the two functions going at the same time, then add the timer to pause the execution. I want it to be able to run one thread for a short time, then move onto another thread, and to keep on doing this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void task1()
{
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        cout << i << '\n';
    }
}

void task2()
{
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        cout << i << '\n';
    }
}

int main()
{
    thread t1(task1);
    thread t2(task2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You've already tried using what?

Comment: I edited the post so it shows.

Comment: Show us the code for your thread.

Comment: I'm hijacking this thread. Regarding your IDT question (now deleted) I ntoiced when I returned home after Christmas Dinner that you had posted a tarball of your code. I assume bynow that you may have discovered the reason it wasn't working because you had commented out the call to `programIDT` before doing division by zero? I corrected that and got the div by zero exception firing and the screen updated.

Answer (score 1):

The most commonly used way of doing this without multi-threading is to abuse the message loop in used by most GUI frameworks. A bit of work is done in a `for` loop and then `PumpMessages` or whatever is called to keep to GUI responsive by processing queued messages and then some more work is done.

In my opinion this is a bad practice. What it actually results in is inconsistent, slow and unresponsive applications.

The other option would be resumable functions such as those available in C# and [proposed for C++17](http://meetingcpp.com/index.php/br/items/resumable-functions-async-and-await.html). However these are not going to be readily available at the moment.

Getting multi-threading right is hard, as you have already discovered crashes and synchronisation bugs are common and can only be found at run time. However multi-core CPUs are the standard everywhere now and you can't really avoid multi-threading so it is best to learn how to get it right.